# Does hard resetting a Virtual Machine carry the same risk that hard resetting a "real" machine does?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization

It is common knowledge that doing a "hard reset" of your personal computer, that is, toggling the power without following the operating system's shutdown/reboot procedure, is a bad idea. It can cause hardware or filesystem damage, and isn't too good for the motherboard.

If I do a hard reset of a Virtual Machine, what am I risking?

Comment: Yes;  It can; For the same reasons;  The virtual machine still has a file system thats what woudl be corrupted.

Comment: Normally the corruptions would occur within the virtual disc, which would not affect the host file system. However, if you were accessing a shared or network folder, discs outside the VM could be corrupted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't cause hardware damage, since no actual hardware has been turned off, but the risk of data corruption (e.g. due to the OS not having finished writing cached data to disk) is the same.